# Fourier Series of $f(x) = (π-x)\mathsf 1_{(0,\pi)}$

Tags: fourier-series

I need to determine the Fourier series of the following function,

$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
0,& \text{ if $-\pi<x<0$}\\
\pi-x,& \text{ if $0<x<\pi$}.
\end{cases}
$$
Also how to plot it.

Comment: This looks like a "do it for me" question.  What have you tried?  What part do you need help?

Comment: I am confused, this looks like a odd function to me hence i think i don't have to calculate a(0) and a(n) as they will be 0 and will only need to find b(n) using (π-x) is that correct assumption?

Comment: I assume this is a periodic function with period $2\pi$, that is, $f(x+2\pi)=f(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$)?

Comment: Also, you are not correct in that this is an odd function. Certainly we do not have $f(-x)=-f(x)$ for all $x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall the expression for the Fourier series:
$$
S(x) = \frac{a_0}2 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\cos(2\pi nx/L) + \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n\sin(2\pi nx/L),
$$
where $L$ is the period of the function (in this case $L=2\pi$. We compute the coefficients:
$$
a_0 = \int_0^\pi (\pi-x)\ \mathsf dx = \frac{\pi^2}2
$$
$$
a_n = \int_0^\pi (\pi-x) \cos nx\ \mathsf ds = \frac{1-\cos \pi n}{n^2}
$$
$$
b_n = \int_0^\pi (\pi-x) \sin nx\ \mathsf ds = \frac{\pi n - \sin \pi n}{n^2},
$$
and hence

$$
S(x) = \frac{\pi^2}4 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1-\cos \pi n}{n^2}\cos nx + \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\pi n - \sin \pi n}{n^2}\sin nx.
$$